# How to get the index of a Window in the Stackset within XMonad?

Tags: xmonad

How can I get the index of a `Window` within a `StackSet`?

I've haad a look through http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-StackSet.html but can't find anything relevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import XMonad.StackSet
import Data.List (elemIndex)


windowIndex :: Window -> StackSet i l Window s sd -> Maybe Int
windowIndex w s = elemIndex w $ allWindowsInCurrentWorkspace s


allWindowsInCurrentWorkspace :: W.StackSet i l a sid sd -> [a]
allWindowsInCurrentWorkspace ws =
  W.integrate' . W.stack . W.workspace . W.current $ ws
```